# How to set values of checkboxes generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

Good morning,i have a table inside a form, the table is populated dynamically from an array list and for each row in that table i have a checkbox and its the first column in the table the second column in the table is an id, i want to set the value attribute of the checkbox with the text in the cell behind it(the id column) when that checkbox is checked as i will get all the values from those checkboxes in a servlet using `request.getParameterValues` when these form is submitted , here's i populate my table :

```
<form name="Main-Form" action="DeleteServlet" method="GET">
    <table BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=YELLOW width="120px" id="product_table">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><b>CarId</b></td>
            <td><b>Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td><b>Price</b></td>
            <td><b>CC.No</b></td>
            <td><b>Engine</b></td>
            <td><b>Cylinder.No</b></td>
            <td><b>MaxSpeed</b></td>
            <td><b>PetrolType</b></td>
            <td><b>PetrolCapacity</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${product_list}" var="car">
            <tr id="data-row">
                <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td> // how to get these checkbox in the for loop
                <td><c:out value="${car.carId}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.carDesc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.quantity}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.price}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.enginCc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.trans}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.noOfCylinder}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.topSpeed}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.fuelType}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.fuelCapacity}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" class="btn1" value="Delete"/>

    </form>
```

Note: DeleteCar is the servlet that will get the values in the chk_group from the request

Comment: Like you would set the value on any other checkbox, it does of course have to exist, but once it does, you can set the value the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if it works

```
$("#myForm > table > tr").each(function(){
     var checkbox = $(this).find("input [type=checkbox]");
     var id = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
     $(this).find("checkbox").val(id);
})
```

Comment: these will fire when any checkbox is checked?

Comment: You can decide the place where you want to execute this logic, probably you have to execute it once your html is generated.. You have to fire it once, and then you can access the checkbox value easily.

Comment: but i want to execute it for only checkboxes that's checked